# How to export database scheme into a file with mysqldump

Tags: mysql, export

I have a problem to save a database into a sql file with Mysql.
Here is my script :

```
CREATE DATABASE DATAImmo

CREATE TABLE TypeBien ( id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE = INNODB
```

Here is the command line to save the sql code :

```
mysqldump -u hao -p --opt DATAImmo > dbexport.sql;
```

the output is :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'mysqldump -u hao -p --opt DATAImmo > dbexport.sql'
> at line 1

Comment: You said "Here is the command line to save the sql code" But you didnt run that from the command line did you. You ran it from within the `mysql>` shell

Comment: If you perform this in CLI then use `SYSTEM` command.

Comment: sorry, I run my command from mysql>

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump` is a shell (command-line) command, not a SQL command.